# как взять значение div с помощью text() только 1 раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста,есть калькулятор на js , фишка в том, что он постоянно парсит значение блока `id="totalsumm"`. Как сделать , чтобы парсинг проходил 1 раз.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

  var totalSumm = 0;
  var saleUp = 1;
  var message = '';
  var totalsumm_node = $("#totalsumm");
  var message_node = $("#message");
  const totalsumm_old = parseInt(totalsumm_node.text());
  $(".calc").on("change" , ".ranks" , function(){

      if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==1){
          totalSumm += 3.26 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==2){
          totalSumm += 22.36 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==3){
          totalSumm += 43.7 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==4){
          totalSumm += 69.54 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==5){
          totalSumm += 98.76 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 120.1 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==1 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 139.2 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==2){
          totalSumm += 17.86 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==3){
          totalSumm += 40.33 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==4){
          totalSumm += 66.17 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==5){
          totalSumm += 95.39 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 116.73 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==2 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 134.71 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==3 && $("#select2").val()==3){
          totalSumm += 22.36 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==3 && $("#select2").val()==4){
          totalSumm += 47.07 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==3 && $("#select2").val()==5){
          totalSumm += 76.29 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==3 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 98.76 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==3 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 116.73 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==4 && $("#select2").val()==4){
          totalSumm += 25.73 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==4 && $("#select2").val()==5){
          totalSumm += 54.94 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==4 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 76.29 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==4 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 95.39 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==5 && $("#select2").val()==5){
          totalSumm += 29.1 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==5 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 51.57 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==5 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 69.54 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==6 && $("#select2").val()==6){
          totalSumm += 22.36 ;
          message = '';
      }
      else if($("#select1").val()==6 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 40.33 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val()==7 && $("#select2").val()==7){
          totalSumm += 36.96 ;
          message = '';
      }


      else if($("#select1").val() && $("#select2").val()==0){
          message = "Выберите обязательно желаемый ранк" ;
      }

      else if($("#select1").val()==0 && $("#select2").val()){
          message = "Выберите ваш ранг" ;
      }
      else {
          message = "Вы хотите понизить себе ранг? Очень странно";
      };
      return;
  });
  $(".calc").on("change" , ".servers" , function(){

      if($("#select-server").val()==1){
          saleUp = 1.1 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==2){
          saleUp = 1.12 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==3){
          saleUp = 1.14 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==4){
          saleUp = 1.16 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==5){
          saleUp = 1.18 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==6){
          saleUp = 1.2 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==7){
          saleUp = 1.22 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==8){
          saleUp = 1.24 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==9){
          saleUp = 1.26 ;
      }
      else if($("#select-server").val()==10){
          saleUp = 1.28 ;
      }
      return;

  });

  $(".calc").on("change" , "select" , function(){

      totalsumm_node.text(totalsumm_old + parseInt(totalSumm*saleUp));
      message_node.text(message);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='calc' action="">
            <select class="ranks" name="" id="select1">
                <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
                <option value="1">Rank 0</option>
                <option value="2">Rank 1</option>
                <option value="3">Rank 2</option>
                <option value="4">Rank 3</option>
                <option value="5">Rank 4</option>
                <option value="6">Rank 5</option>
                <option value="7">Rank 6</option>
            </select>
            <select class="ranks" name="" id="select2">
                <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
                <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
                <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
                <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
                <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
                <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
                <option value="6">Rank 6</option>
                <option value="7">Rank 7</option>
            </select>
            
            <select class="servers" name="" id="select-server">
                <option value="0">Выберите свой сервер</option>
                <option value="1">EU west</option>
                <option value="2">EU nordic & east</option>
                <option value="3">North america</option>
                <option value="4">Russia</option>
                <option value="5">Turkey</option>
                <option value="6">Oceania</option>
                <option value="7">Japan</option>            
                <option value="8">Latin America North</option>            
                <option value="9">Latin America South</option>                       
                <option value="10">Brazil</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="totalsumm">0</div>
        <div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: В вашем случае totalsumm_node - ссылка на DOM элемент. В обработчик события $(".calc").on("change" , "select"... вы положили totalsumm_node.text - который "парсит" содержимое блока $("#totalsumm"). Что бы вытащить значение единожды и далее с ним работать - необходимо вынести метод .text за пределы обработчика события change.

Comment: даа , я понимаю это , но как его вынести , либо я очень жестко туплю либо чего то не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Пардоньте, но вся ваша лютая портянка кода делает то, что ниже приведено?

```js
  var x_tbl = [,
     [,3.26, 22.36, 43.7],
     [,,17.86, 40.33],
     [,,,47.07, 76.29]
  ];
  

  $("select").change(function(){      
      $("#total").text(null);
      var $msg = $("#msg").text(null);
  
      var cr = +$("#current").val();
      var tr = +$("#target").val();          
      
      if(!cr&&tr)      $msg.text("выберите что-нибудь");
      else if(!tr)     $msg.text("выберите желаемый");
      else if(tr < cr) $msg.text("понизить?");
      else {
        var k = +$("#server").val() || 1;        
        $("#total").text( k * x_tbl[cr][tr] || 0);
      }      
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select id="current">
        <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
        <option value="1">Rank 0</option>
        <option value="2">Rank 1</option>
        <option value="3">Rank 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="target">
        <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
        <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
        <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
        <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="server">
        <option value="0">Выберите свой сервер</option>
        <option value="1.1">EU west</option>
        <option value="1.12">EU nordic & east</option>
        <option value="1.14">North america</option>
        <option value="1.16">Russia</option>
    </select>
<div id="total">____</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```